# Remove fails from ansible play recap

Tags: python, jenkins, ansible

I have an ansible playbook that will have some intermittent failed jobs in the play recap like so

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server1    : ok=10    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
server2    : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   
server3    : ok=10    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The fails cause the jenkins job running the playbook to fail, but it needs to pass to continue in the pipeline. Is there a way to remove failed jobs from the play recap?

Comment: Which task is failling? Is it always the same task?

Comment: Wait, you just want to remove the non-0 failure in this log output?

Answer (score 0):

The first question to ask is why the tasks are actually failing. If you have certain tasks that can fail without any negative impact you can run them with "ignore_errors: yes" that way it Ansible will just continue to the next task as if the current module hadn't failed and the output won't indicate a failure.

Another solution would be to use a callback plugin which is the part of Ansible which handles the actual output from a playbook. By default, the "default" callback plugin is used. There are however a lot of callback plugins included in Ansible. You can see a list of them in the source code:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback

You could either try different callback plugins which you can set in ansible.cfg using the "stdout_callback" parameter. Depending on what you want to do you could use the null callback which won't print out anything.

If you need the number of tasks which were ok, changed and unreachable you might need to create your own callback. This could be done by creating a copy of the default callback and editing out the section which prints the number of failed tasks.